# Hide table data if value is in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I am trying to hide TD on a table if the TD's value is in an array that I specify.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr class="tr-2">
        <td class="weeknd">22</td>
        <td class="weeknd">23</td>
        <td class="weeknd">24</td>
        <td class="weeknd">25</td>
        <td class="weeknd">26</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

and scripts

```
    const myarray = [22,23,24,25];
    var weeknd = Array();


    $(myarray).each(function(i) {
        console.log(myarray[i])
    })

    $(".weeknd").each(function(index, i){
       weeknd[index] = $(this).text();
        if(weeknd[index] == myarray[i]){
            $(this).hide()
        }
    })
```

and here is the Codepen: https://codepen.io/Xteripus/pen/yLMmZqw?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the content is in `myarray`:

```js
const myarray = [22,23,24,25];

$(".weeknd").each(function() {
   if(myarray.includes(+$(this).text())) $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <tr class="tr-2">
    <td class="weeknd">22</td>
    <td class="weeknd">23</td>
    <td class="weeknd">24</td>
    <td class="weeknd">25</td>
    <td class="weeknd">26</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you require you can loop through each `td` and use `toggle()` to hide/show them based on the result of `indexOf()`, comparing the `td` text to the values in the array. Try this:

```js
const myarray = [22, 23, 24, 25];

jQuery($ => {
  $('.weeknd').each((i, el) => $(el).toggle(myarray.indexOf(parseInt(el.textContent, 10)) === -1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="tr-2">
    <td class="weeknd">22</td>
    <td class="weeknd">23</td>
    <td class="weeknd">24</td>
    <td class="weeknd">25</td>
    <td class="weeknd">26</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much works like a a charm but it looks like magic and too complicated to me and. Any advices to learn this power?

Comment: Sure, the jQuery and MDN JS documentation is very thorough. You can Google each method name to get a full description of their functionality. [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each), [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle), [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will Google all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by adding some simple indexes in your HTML like this:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr class="tr-2">
        <td id="weeknd22" class="weeknd">22</td>
        <td id="weeknd23" class="weeknd">23</td>
        <td id="weeknd24" class="weeknd">24</td>
        <td id="weeknd25" class="weeknd">25</td>
        <td id="weeknd26" class="weeknd">26</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This now makes it easy to hide those that are in the array by doing this

```
const myarray = [22,23,24,25];

    myarray.forEach(function(e){
    
        var el = document.getElementById("weeknd"+e);
        if (el) el.style.display="none";
    
    })
```

I have used plain old JavaScript as it shows how easy you can do this. Of course you can use jQuery and adapt the principles that I have used.

If for example you do not want to use ID's (or you have multiple TD's of the same number) you can add a class such as .weeknd22 and use that as a look-up reference into your Dom to find the matching TD's. If you use .querySelectorAll(".weeknd22") it will allow for multiple matches.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr=[22,23,24,25];
document.querySelectorAll(".weeknd")
  .forEach(td=>td.style.visibility=arr.includes(+td.textContent)?"hidden":"visible");
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr class="tr-2">
    <td class="weeknd">22</td>
    <td class="weeknd">23</td>
    <td class="weeknd">24</td>
    <td class="weeknd">25</td>
    <td class="weeknd">26</td>
</tr>
</table>
```